How may I increase the speed of SCF iterations in SIESTA?
I have experience with VASP and CASTEP, but since I need to use TRANSIESTA to calculate transport properties, I tried to use siesta. I heard that siesta is very fast and can handle large systems, but when I calculated a 156-atom hybrid halide perovskite material, I found that the speed was very slow when using the DZP basis set. It took ten hours to calculate a few ion steps. I tried using GGA-PBE or LDA-PW92 exchange functionals, and tried different pseudopotential sources.
I have tried pseudopotential sources from the following website
http://www.pseudo-dojo.org/ and https://www.simuneatomistics.com/siesta-pro/siesta-pseudos-and-basis-database/
I tried to increase PAO.Energyshift and PAO.SplitNorm, but make little difference.
The workstation I used has 24 physical cores and 48 threads, 192GB of RAM and 1TB of SSD. During the calculation, I used 24 threads.
It is worth mentioning that I have no elpa library installed.I can't install the elpa library on our workstations anyway,As I mentioned in this question,elpa installation problem, and I'm curious to what extent this library can speed up calculations
Here is my siesta input file for monolayer (BA)2PbBr4.
SystemName 4517593monolayer.poscar
SystemLabel 4517593monolayer.poscar

NumberOfAtoms 78
NumberOfSpecies 5


%block kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack
 4   0   0    0.0
  0  4   0    0.0
  0   0   1    0.0
%endblock kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack


%block Chemical_Species_label
1 35 Br
2 7 N
3 1 H
4 6 C
5 82 Pb
%endblock Chemical_Species_label

LatticeConstant 1.0 Ang
%block LatticeVectors
 8.3343000412 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
 0.0000000000 8.2224998474 0.0000000000
 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 27.6170997620
%endblock LatticeVectors


AtomicCoordinatesFormat Ang
%block  AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies
8.0476 8.0589 16.8050 1
4.4538 3.9476 16.8050 1
2.5428 1.5960 13.8804 1
1.6244 5.7072 13.8804 1
6.7099 2.5153 13.7367 1
5.7915 6.6265 13.7367 1
0.2867 0.1636 10.8121 1
3.8805 4.2749 10.8121 1
7.7176 4.7082 16.2665 2
4.7839 0.5970 16.2665 2
0.6167 3.5143 11.3506 2
3.5504 7.6255 11.3506 2
2.6620 6.6273 21.1105 3
1.5052 2.5161 21.1105 3
3.0262 8.1460 20.9724 3
1.1410 4.0348 20.9724 3
0.0133 2.9486 20.8951 3
4.1538 7.0598 20.8951 3
2.0211 3.3128 18.9702 3
2.1461 7.4241 18.9702 3
0.9818 2.1387 18.9094 3
3.1854 6.2499 18.9094 3
0.2759 4.8677 18.7492 3
3.8913 0.7565 18.7492 3
7.5725 3.6919 18.6857 3
4.9289 7.8032 18.6857 3
2.9228 0.0230 16.7774 3
1.2443 4.1343 16.7774 3
3.9363 7.0500 16.7166 3
0.2309 2.9387 16.7166 3
7.8367 5.5592 16.5012 3
4.6647 1.4480 16.5012 3
6.8866 4.4591 16.4681 3
5.6148 0.3478 16.4681 3
4.6514 0.5082 15.3910 3
7.8501 4.6194 15.3910 3
0.4842 3.6031 12.2261 3
3.6829 7.7143 12.2261 3
2.7195 7.8747 11.1490 3
1.4477 3.7634 11.1490 3
3.6696 6.7745 11.1159 3
0.4976 2.6633 11.1159 3
4.3980 1.1725 10.9005 3
8.1034 5.2838 10.9005 3
5.4115 8.1995 10.8397 3
7.0900 4.0882 10.8397 3
0.7618 4.5306 8.9314 3
3.4054 0.4193 8.9314 3
4.4430 7.4660 8.8679 3
8.0584 3.3548 8.8679 3
7.3525 6.0838 8.7077 3
5.1489 1.9726 8.7077 3
6.1882 0.7984 8.6469 3
6.3132 4.9097 8.6469 3
4.1805 1.1627 6.7220 3
8.3210 5.2739 6.7220 3
5.3081 0.0765 6.6447 3
7.1933 4.1877 6.6447 3
5.6723 1.5952 6.5066 3
6.8291 5.7064 6.5066 3
0.9268 3.1468 20.6742 4
3.2404 7.2580 20.6742 4
1.1135 3.0571 19.1966 4
3.0537 7.1684 19.1966 4
0.1467 3.9501 18.4648 4
4.0205 8.0613 18.4648 4
0.3409 3.8605 16.9983 4
3.8263 7.9717 16.9983 4
4.5080 0.2508 10.6188 4
7.9934 4.3620 10.6188 4
4.3138 0.1612 9.1523 4
8.1876 4.2724 9.1523 4
5.2806 1.0541 8.4205 4
7.2208 5.1654 8.4205 4
7.4075 5.0757 6.9429 4
5.0939 0.9645 6.9429 4
0.0000 0.0000 13.8085 5
4.1672 4.1112 13.8085 5
%endblock  AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies

    # -- SELF-CONSISTENT FIELD --

MeshCutoff      100 Ry
PAO.BasisType       split
PAO.BasisSize       DZP
PAO.EnergyShift     0.03 eV
XC.functional           GGA
XC.authors              PBE
MaxSCFIterations        100
SolutionMethod          diagon

    # -- SELF-CONSISTENT FIELD-MIXING --

SCF.Mixer.Weight        0.25
SCF.Mixer.Method        Pulay
SCF.Mixer.History       6
SCF.Mix.AfterConvergence false
DM.FormattedFiles       T
DM.FormattedOutput      T


DFTD3      T   

# -- MOLECULAR DYNAMICS-CONJUGATE-GRADIENT-METHOD --

MD.TypeOfRun             CG
MD.VariableCell          true
MD.MaxForceTol           0.02 eV/Ang
MD.MaxStressTol          0.02 GPa
MD.Steps                 300
MD.MaxDispl              0.2 Bohr



    # -- GEOMETRY CONSTRAINTS --

%block GeometryConstraints
cell-angle  gamma
%endblock GeometryConstraints 


And grep 'Cell vector modules' gives
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.334300    8.222500   27.617100
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.358814    8.246685   27.617100
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.398036    8.285380   27.617100
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.460791    8.347294   27.617100
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.561198    8.446355   27.617100
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.480751    8.366986   27.617100
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.304338    8.192940   27.617100
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.127925    8.018893   27.617100
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.951512    7.844847   27.617100
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.775100    7.670801   27.617100
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.598687    7.496755   27.617100
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.636093    7.533659   27.617100
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.459681    7.359613   27.617100
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.283268    7.185567   27.617100
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.288800    7.191024   27.617100
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.339639    7.241182   27.617100

It was obvious that the lattice constant was getting further and further away from the experimental lattice constant,so I stopped calculating.
Experimental lattice constants from reference 'DOI: 10.1126/science.aac7660'
a = 8.2530(2) Å a= 90°.
b = 8.1375(2) Å b= 90°.
c = 27.4028(9) Å g = 90°.

Here is the CLOCK file
Start of run             0.000
-------------- end of scf step           319.385
-------------- end of scf step           562.205
-------------- end of scf step           809.109
-------------- end of scf step          1051.451
-------------- end of scf step          1294.337
-------------- end of scf step          1540.776
-------------- end of scf step          1783.246
-------------- end of scf step          2024.723
-------------- end of scf step          2267.960
-------------- end of scf step          2510.824
-------------- end of scf step          2753.850
-------------- end of scf step          2994.779
-------------- end of scf step          3238.118
-------------- end of scf step          3478.829
-------------- end of scf step          3722.077
-------------- end of scf step          3965.207
-------------- end of scf step          4207.050
--- end of geometry step          4220.235
-------------- end of scf step          4467.595
-------------- end of scf step          4711.021
-------------- end of scf step          4955.697
-------------- end of scf step          5197.964
-------------- end of scf step          5445.346
-------------- end of scf step          5686.607
-------------- end of scf step          5932.713
-------------- end of scf step          6174.701
-------------- end of scf step          6420.252
-------------- end of scf step          6664.670
-------------- end of scf step          6905.809
--- end of geometry step          6917.753
-------------- end of scf step          7162.155
-------------- end of scf step          7404.125
-------------- end of scf step          7646.670
-------------- end of scf step          7889.890
-------------- end of scf step          8134.451
-------------- end of scf step          8377.202
-------------- end of scf step          8621.687
-------------- end of scf step          8865.172
-------------- end of scf step          9109.605
-------------- end of scf step          9351.280
-------------- end of scf step          9599.826
-------------- end of scf step          9843.617
............
--- end of geometry step         13512.797
-------------- end of scf step         13760.416
-------------- end of scf step         14003.504
-------------- end of scf step         14246.215
-------------- end of scf step         14488.434
-------------- end of scf step         14734.805
-------------- end of scf step         14980.174
-------------- end of scf step         15219.714
-------------- end of scf step         15467.520
-------------- end of scf step         15710.257
-------------- end of scf step         15950.882
-------------- end of scf step         16193.623
-------------- end of scf step         16436.691
-------------- end of scf step         16678.828
-------------- end of scf step         16920.206
-------------- end of scf step         17162.741
-------------- end of scf step         17406.385
-------------- end of scf step         17648.808
-------------- end of scf step         17858.560
--- end of geometry step         17864.832
-------------- end of scf step         18068.104
-------------- end of scf step         18314.584
-------------- end of scf step         18560.982
-------------- end of scf step         18808.561
-------------- end of scf step         19054.911
-------------- end of scf step         19298.541
-------------- end of scf step         19542.801
-------------- end of scf step         19789.985
-------------- end of scf step         20034.044
-------------- end of scf step         20277.889
-------------- end of scf step         20520.350
-------------- end of scf step         20770.441
-------------- end of scf step         21011.415
-------------- end of scf step         21252.910
-------------- end of scf step         21495.930
-------------- end of scf step         21738.156
--- end of geometry step         21749.185
-------------- end of scf step         21994.632
-------------- end of scf step         22235.967
-------------- end of scf step         22477.737
-------------- end of scf step         22718.928
-------------- end of scf step         22960.573
-------------- end of scf step         23202.478
-------------- end of scf step         23443.233
-------------- end of scf step         23684.896
-------------- end of scf step         23927.748
-------------- end of scf step         24169.731
-------------- end of scf step         24417.123
-------------- end of scf step         24663.976
-------------- end of scf step         24907.516
-------------- end of scf step         25152.970
-------------- end of scf step         25399.468
-------------- end of scf step         25644.568
-------------- end of scf step         25889.382
-------------- end of scf step         26136.904
--- end of geometry step         26149.859
-------------- end of scf step         26399.198
-------------- end of scf step         26646.785
-------------- end of scf step         26892.767
-------------- end of scf step         27137.947
-------------- end of scf step         27381.886
-------------- end of scf step         27622.854
-------------- end of scf step         27866.165
-------------- end of scf step         28110.356
-------------- end of scf step         28350.114
-------------- end of scf step         28591.766
-------------- end of scf step         28832.365
-------------- end of scf step         29076.027
-------------- end of scf step         29317.616
-------------- end of scf step         29561.079
-------------- end of scf step         29808.391
-------------- end of scf step         30053.920
-------------- end of scf step         30299.798
--- end of geometry step         30313.699
-------------- end of scf step         30588.584
-------------- end of scf step         30838.453
-------------- end of scf step         31087.030
-------------- end of scf step         31332.609
-------------- end of scf step         31572.941
-------------- end of scf step         31819.545
-------------- end of scf step         32064.073
-------------- end of scf step         32309.541
-------------- end of scf step         32552.550
-------------- end of scf step         32797.798
-------------- end of scf step         33038.773
-------------- end of scf step         33284.183
-------------- end of scf step         33528.649
-------------- end of scf step         33773.450
-------------- end of scf step         34021.328
-------------- end of scf step         34280.197
--- end of geometry step         34294.463
-------------- end of scf step         34552.119
-------------- end of scf step         34803.579
-------------- end of scf step         35054.105
-------------- end of scf step         35304.592
-------------- end of scf step         35558.829
-------------- end of scf step         35810.516
-------------- end of scf step         36064.572
-------------- end of scf step         36320.026
-------------- end of scf step         36570.150
-------------- end of scf step         36827.177
-------------- end of scf step         37077.943
-------------- end of scf step         37320.861
-------------- end of scf step         37568.830
-------------- end of scf step         37813.982
-------------- end of scf step         38054.723
-------------- end of scf step         38302.198
-------------- end of scf step         38548.097
--- end of geometry step         38563.290
-------------- end of scf step         38812.959
-------------- end of scf step         39056.218
-------------- end of scf step         39299.849
-------------- end of scf step         39540.787
-------------- end of scf step         39783.290
-------------- end of scf step         40025.462
-------------- end of scf step         40267.143
-------------- end of scf step         40509.381
-------------- end of scf step         40750.926
-------------- end of scf step         40993.539
-------------- end of scf step         41237.364
-------------- end of scf step         41480.040
-------------- end of scf step         41721.404
-------------- end of scf step         41963.724
-------------- end of scf step         42209.022
-------------- end of scf step         42454.036
-------------- end of scf step         42698.345
-------------- end of scf step         42942.761
--- end of geometry step         42959.382
-------------- end of scf step         43207.382
-------------- end of scf step         43452.737
-------------- end of scf step         43701.594
-------------- end of scf step         43948.023
-------------- end of scf step         44194.927
-------------- end of scf step         44439.070
-------------- end of scf step         44684.728
-------------- end of scf step         44932.806
-------------- end of scf step         45175.246
-------------- end of scf step         45419.053
-------------- end of scf step         45659.229
-------------- end of scf step         45900.733
-------------- end of scf step         46143.412
--- end of geometry step         46159.175
-------------- end of scf step         46406.617
-------------- end of scf step         46653.064
-------------- end of scf step         46897.019
-------------- end of scf step         47142.129
-------------- end of scf step         47390.584
-------------- end of scf step         47635.293
-------------- end of scf step         47878.720
-------------- end of scf step         48124.586
-------------- end of scf step         48370.351
-------------- end of scf step         48618.651
-------------- end of scf step         48865.727
-------------- end of scf step         49114.982
-------------- end of scf step         49357.758
-------------- end of scf step         49604.734
-------------- end of scf step         49858.475
-------------- end of scf step         50103.115
-------------- end of scf step         50352.580
-------------- end of scf step         50596.654
-------------- end of scf step         50841.236
--- end of geometry step         50858.617
-------------- end of scf step         51104.179
-------------- end of scf step         51347.391
-------------- end of scf step         51592.422
-------------- end of scf step         51837.009
-------------- end of scf step         52080.903
-------------- end of scf step         52325.065
-------------- end of scf step         52575.246
-------------- end of scf step         52823.380
-------------- end of scf step         53068.593
-------------- end of scf step         53312.384
-------------- end of scf step         53579.174
-------------- end of scf step         53824.463
-------------- end of scf step         54072.973
-------------- end of scf step         54321.063
-------------- end of scf step         54573.441
-------------- end of scf step         54819.651
-------------- end of scf step         55070.566
-------------- end of scf step         55317.558
-------------- end of scf step         55566.232
--- end of geometry step         55586.368
-------------- end of scf step         55835.917
-------------- end of scf step         56088.099
-------------- end of scf step         56336.180
-------------- end of scf step         56584.128
-------------- end of scf step         56831.361
-------------- end of scf step         57074.973
-------------- end of scf step         57319.636
-------------- end of scf step         57563.465
--- end of geometry step         57583.866
-------------- end of scf step         57832.605
-------------- end of scf step         58075.694
-------------- end of scf step         58320.447
-------------- end of scf step         58565.877
-------------- end of scf step         58813.121


Here is my siesta input file for bulk (BA)2PbBr4. And I didn't include DFT-D3 correction this time.DFT-D3 is not compatible with LDA functional.
SystemName 4517593.poscar
SystemLabel 4517593.poscar

NumberOfAtoms 156
NumberOfSpecies 5

%block Chemical_Species_label
1 82 Pb
2 35 Br
3 7 N
4 1 H
5 6 C
%endblock Chemical_Species_label

LatticeConstant 1.0 Ang
%block LatticeVectors
 8.3343000412 0.0000000000 0.0000000000
 0.0000000000 8.2224998474 0.0000000000
 0.0000000000 0.0000000000 27.6170997620
%endblock LatticeVectors


AtomicCoordinatesFormat Ang
%block  AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies
4.1672 4.1112 13.8085 1
0.0000 0.0000 13.8085 1
0.0000 4.1112 0.0000 1
4.1672 0.0000 0.0000 1
6.7099 1.5960 27.5453 2
5.7915 5.7072 27.5453 2
3.8805 8.0589 24.6206 2
0.2867 3.9476 24.6206 2
8.0476 8.0589 16.8050 2
4.4538 3.9476 16.8050 2
1.6244 5.7072 13.8804 2
2.5428 1.5960 13.8804 2
5.7915 6.6265 13.7367 2
6.7099 2.5153 13.7367 2
0.2867 0.1636 10.8121 2
3.8805 4.2749 10.8121 2
8.0476 4.2749 2.9965 2
4.4538 0.1636 2.9965 2
1.6244 6.6265 0.0718 2
2.5428 2.5153 0.0718 2
3.5504 4.7082 25.1592 3
0.6167 0.5970 25.1592 3
4.7839 0.5970 16.2665 3
7.7176 4.7082 16.2665 3
3.5504 7.6255 11.3506 3
0.6167 3.5143 11.3506 3
7.7176 7.6255 2.4579 3
4.7839 3.5143 2.4579 3
0.4842 0.5082 26.0346 4
3.6829 4.6194 26.0346 4
1.4477 0.3478 24.9576 4
2.7195 4.4591 24.9576 4
0.4976 1.4480 24.9244 4
3.6696 5.5592 24.9244 4
8.1034 7.0500 24.7090 4
4.3980 2.9387 24.7090 4
5.4115 4.1343 24.6483 4
7.0900 0.0230 24.6483 4
3.4054 3.6919 22.7399 4
0.7618 7.8032 22.7399 4
4.4430 4.8677 22.6764 4
8.0584 0.7565 22.6764 4
5.1489 2.1387 22.5162 4
7.3525 6.2499 22.5162 4
6.3132 7.4241 22.4555 4
6.1882 3.3128 22.4555 4
1.5052 2.5161 21.1105 4
2.6620 6.6273 21.1105 4
1.1410 4.0348 20.9724 4
3.0262 8.1460 20.9724 4
0.0133 2.9486 20.8951 4
4.1538 7.0598 20.8951 4
4.1805 2.9486 20.5306 4
8.3210 7.0598 20.5306 4
7.1933 8.1460 20.4532 4
5.3081 4.0348 20.4532 4
6.8291 6.6273 20.3151 4
5.6723 2.5161 20.3151 4
2.1461 7.4241 18.9702 4
2.0211 3.3128 18.9702 4
0.9818 2.1387 18.9094 4
3.1854 6.2499 18.9094 4
0.2759 4.8677 18.7492 4
3.8913 0.7565 18.7492 4
7.5725 3.6919 18.6857 4
4.9289 7.8032 18.6857 4
1.2443 4.1343 16.7774 4
2.9228 0.0230 16.7774 4
3.9363 7.0500 16.7166 4
0.2309 2.9387 16.7166 4
7.8367 5.5592 16.5012 4
4.6647 1.4480 16.5012 4
5.6148 0.3478 16.4681 4
6.8866 4.4591 16.4681 4
7.8501 4.6194 15.3910 4
4.6514 0.5082 15.3910 4
0.4842 3.6031 12.2261 4
3.6829 7.7143 12.2261 4
2.7195 7.8747 11.1490 4
1.4477 3.7634 11.1490 4
3.6696 6.7745 11.1159 4
0.4976 2.6633 11.1159 4
4.3980 1.1725 10.9005 4
8.1034 5.2838 10.9005 4
5.4115 8.1995 10.8397 4
7.0900 4.0882 10.8397 4
3.4054 0.4193 8.9314 4
0.7618 4.5306 8.9314 4
4.4430 7.4660 8.8679 4
8.0584 3.3548 8.8679 4
7.3525 6.0838 8.7077 4
5.1489 1.9726 8.7077 4
6.1882 0.7984 8.6469 4
6.3132 4.9097 8.6469 4
1.5052 1.5952 7.3020 4
2.6620 5.7064 7.3020 4
1.1410 0.0765 7.1639 4
3.0262 4.1877 7.1639 4
0.0133 1.1627 7.0865 4
4.1538 5.2739 7.0865 4
8.3210 5.2739 6.7220 4
4.1805 1.1627 6.7220 4
7.1933 4.1877 6.6447 4
5.3081 0.0765 6.6447 4
6.8291 5.7064 6.5066 4
5.6723 1.5952 6.5066 4
2.0211 0.7984 5.1616 4
2.1461 4.9097 5.1616 4
0.9818 1.9726 5.1009 4
3.1854 6.0838 5.1009 4
3.8913 3.3548 4.9407 4
0.2759 7.4660 4.9407 4
4.9289 4.5306 4.8772 4
7.5725 0.4193 4.8772 4
1.2443 8.1995 2.9688 4
2.9228 4.0882 2.9688 4
3.9363 5.2838 2.9081 4
0.2309 1.1725 2.9081 4
7.8367 6.7745 2.6927 4
4.6647 2.6633 2.6927 4
5.6148 3.7634 2.6595 4
6.8866 7.8747 2.6595 4
7.8501 7.7143 1.5825 4
4.6514 3.6031 1.5825 4
7.9934 7.9717 24.4273 5
4.5080 3.8605 24.4273 5
8.1876 8.0613 22.9609 5
4.3138 3.9501 22.9609 5
7.2208 7.1684 22.2290 5
5.2806 3.0571 22.2290 5
7.4075 7.2580 20.7515 5
5.0939 3.1468 20.7515 5
3.2404 7.2580 20.6742 5
0.9268 3.1468 20.6742 5
1.1135 3.0571 19.1966 5
3.0537 7.1684 19.1966 5
0.1467 3.9501 18.4648 5
4.0205 8.0613 18.4648 5
0.3409 3.8605 16.9983 5
3.8263 7.9717 16.9983 5
7.9934 4.3620 10.6188 5
4.5080 0.2508 10.6188 5
8.1876 4.2724 9.1523 5
4.3138 0.1612 9.1523 5
5.2806 1.0541 8.4205 5
7.2208 5.1654 8.4205 5
5.0939 0.9645 6.9429 5
7.4075 5.0757 6.9429 5
0.9268 0.9645 6.8656 5
3.2404 5.0757 6.8656 5
3.0537 5.1654 5.3881 5
1.1135 1.0541 5.3881 5
0.1467 0.1612 4.6562 5
4.0205 4.2724 4.6562 5
3.8263 4.3620 3.1898 5
0.3409 0.2508 3.1898 5
%endblock  AtomicCoordinatesAndAtomicSpecies



%block kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack
  3   0   0    0.0
  0   3   0    0.0
  0   0   1    0.0
%endblock kgrid_Monkhorst_Pack



    # -- SELF-CONSISTENT FIELD --

Mesh.Cutoff     150 Ry
PAO.BasisType       split
PAO.BasisSize       DZP
PAO.EnergyShift     1 eV
PAO.SplitNorm           0.5
XC.functional           LDA
XC.authors              PW92
MaxSCFIterations        100
SolutionMethod          diagon

    # -- SELF-CONSISTENT FIELD-MIXING --

SCF.Mixer.Weight        0.25
SCF.Mixer.Method        Pulay
SCF.Mixer.History       10
SCF.Mix.AfterConvergence false
DM.FormattedFiles       T
DM.FormattedOutput      T



# -- MOLECULAR DYNAMICS-CONJUGATE-GRADIENT-METHOD --

MD.TypeOfRun             CG
MD.VariableCell          true
MD.MaxForceTol           0.05 eV/Ang
#MD.MaxStressTol          1 GPa
MD.Steps                 300
MD.MaxDispl              0.2 Bohr


And grep 'Cell vector modules' gives
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.334300    8.222500   27.617100
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.370043    8.265699   27.626150
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.427232    8.334817   27.640630
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.518734    8.445407   27.663798
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.662741    8.619453   27.700261
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.594824    8.537369   27.683064
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.420314    8.363322   27.440974
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.245804    8.189276   27.198883
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    8.071294    8.015230   26.956793
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.896784    7.841183   26.714702
outcell: Cell vector modules (Ang)   :    7.722275    7.667137   26.472612

Here is the CLOCK file,
Start of run             0.000
-------------- end of scf step           692.043
-------------- end of scf step          1366.317
-------------- end of scf step          2040.522
-------------- end of scf step          2712.224
-------------- end of scf step          3385.098
-------------- end of scf step          4055.691
-------------- end of scf step          4730.439
-------------- end of scf step          5401.959
-------------- end of scf step          6074.997
-------------- end of scf step          6749.320
--- end of geometry step          6749.584
-------------- end of scf step          7419.857
-------------- end of scf step          8093.067
-------------- end of scf step          8772.841
-------------- end of scf step          9442.237
-------------- end of scf step         10121.720
-------------- end of scf step         10791.184
-------------- end of scf step         11481.514
-------------- end of scf step         12195.983
--- end of geometry step         12196.286
-------------- end of scf step         12911.303
-------------- end of scf step         13616.515
-------------- end of scf step         14323.689
-------------- end of scf step         15013.937
-------------- end of scf step         15687.835
-------------- end of scf step         16361.172
-------------- end of scf step         17034.409
-------------- end of scf step         17710.656
--- end of geometry step         17710.927
-------------- end of scf step         18385.416
-------------- end of scf step         19060.137
-------------- end of scf step         19730.514
-------------- end of scf step         20400.098
-------------- end of scf step         21072.820
-------------- end of scf step         21743.634
-------------- end of scf step         22413.785
-------------- end of scf step         23087.089
--- end of geometry step         23087.331
-------------- end of scf step         23764.626
-------------- end of scf step         24439.870
-------------- end of scf step         25112.636
-------------- end of scf step         25784.501
-------------- end of scf step         26457.627
-------------- end of scf step         27130.740
-------------- end of scf step         27802.957
-------------- end of scf step         28476.042
-------------- end of scf step         29147.851
--- end of geometry step         29148.096
-------------- end of scf step         29819.276
-------------- end of scf step         30493.310
-------------- end of scf step         31164.586
-------------- end of scf step         31839.052
-------------- end of scf step         32512.576
-------------- end of scf step         33185.975
-------------- end of scf step         33856.982
-------------- end of scf step         34529.854
--- end of geometry step         34530.134
-------------- end of scf step         35208.333
-------------- end of scf step         35880.151
-------------- end of scf step         36553.742
-------------- end of scf step         37227.168
-------------- end of scf step         37900.747
-------------- end of scf step         38572.430
-------------- end of scf step         39247.155
-------------- end of scf step         39922.233
--- end of geometry step         39922.486
-------------- end of scf step         40596.236
-------------- end of scf step         41266.814
-------------- end of scf step         41943.897
-------------- end of scf step         42618.357
-------------- end of scf step         43286.508
-------------- end of scf step         43963.937
-------------- end of scf step         44637.749
-------------- end of scf step         45311.793
--- end of geometry step         45312.067
-------------- end of scf step         45983.429
-------------- end of scf step         46659.665
-------------- end of scf step         47332.624
-------------- end of scf step         48007.549
-------------- end of scf step         48681.119
-------------- end of scf step         49357.313
-------------- end of scf step         50030.940
-------------- end of scf step         50706.412
--- end of geometry step         50706.664
-------------- end of scf step         51382.066


Here is the header of output file.
Executable      : siesta
Version         : 5.0.0
Architecture    : x86_64
Compiler version: GNU-14.1.0
Compiler flags  : -fallow-argument-mismatch -O3 -march=native
Parallelisations: MPI
NetCDF support
NetCDF-4 support
Lua support
DFT-D3 support

Runtime information:
* Directory : /Users/grouphwang/projects/perovskitepsedoBAPbBr/relax/perovskite19
* Running on 24 nodes in parallel.


+1. Welcome to our community.

@Camps Thank you for refining this question，Sir！

Could you add more information related to the actual simulation? Siesta's speed heavily depends on basis set generation + settings... To me it sounds like a sub-optimal usage of options...

@nickpapior Good morning from South Korea, Sir. I have uploaded my siesta input file and part of the output file.

likely your very high mixing weight means that the SCF cycle takes very long, check how the SCF cycle look? How many iterations per step?

@nickpapior Sir, there are around 10 to 20 iterations per step, as we can see from the CLOCK file. And I think each scf iteration takes too much time.

Then I would guess your linear algrebra routines are old, which libraries are you using? Also, try and remove the DM.Formatted options, they can be quite heavy and not needed.

A more specific title would be helpful.

@nickpapior Sir, I am using openblas and scalapack for dealing with linear algrebra, which are all latest. It is worth mentioning that I have no elpa library installed.I can't install the elpa library on our workstations anyway. and I'm curious to what extent this library can speed up calculations. I have comment on DM.Formatted options and re-run the calculations.

@NikeDattani-NoFreeTime Thank you, Sir, I have done it

How many questions are you asking?

When running other codes, I have sometimes experienced issues with openblas creating multiple threads which end up oversubscribing the CPU cores, thus slowing down the calculations. Could you check if that is happening? If you have 24 physical cores and 24 MPI ranks, I think you should avoid any threading.

@jme52 comment is very valid here, ensure export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 in your case

@NikeDattani-NoFreeTime Sir, my question focuses on calculation speed of siesta

@NikeDattani-NoFreeTime Thank you for refining this question, Sir

@xinbiaowang all I did was add a tag to your quesiton, but can you please answer my question?

@NikeDattani-NoFreeTime Sir, during my calculation of (BA)2PbBr4 materials using siesta, I found the speed is unexpectedly slow. And I found the indeed problem is each scf step takes too much time. So there is only one question, which is why  calculation of (BA)2PbBr4 materials using siesta takes too much time.

and @xinbiaowang did you try forcing threads to 1?

@nickpapior Sir,I can't follow you. Could you explain how to force threads to 1?

@nickpapior I didn't include openmp during compiling siesta

@nickpapior Sir, I recompiled siesta with openmp on, then, I use 24 cores and each cores with 8 threads to rerun the calculations, I found the speed is indeed faster than ever

@nickpapior what makes me confused is that our workstation has 24 physical cores and 48 threads. Why could I call 24*8=192 threads to do the calculation?

@xinbiaowang your question about how to increase the speed of your calculations seems to have been answered: compile with OpenMP and use more than one thread. Your new question about using more threads than your computer "has", belongs in a new post.

@xinbiaowang the point is that by default openblas will use many threads, by forcing it to only use 1 then you won't use 24*8=192 threads.
You are not following the instructions we told... 1) compile siesta without openmp support, 2) set OMP_NUM_THREADS to 1, 3) run siesta normally.

@nickpapior Sir, follow your instructions, I run the siesta using the following command,mpirun --map-by ppr:12:node -x OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 siesta INPUT.fdf > out, the speed is unbelievably fast! Even though I just call 12 cores, it is far faster than mpirun --map-by ppr:24:node -x OMP_NUM_THREADS=8 siesta INPUT.fdf > out or mpirun --map-by ppr:12:node -x OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 siesta INPUT.fdf > out. You save my life, Sir!

Generally one should be very careful on using threaded BLAS libraries together with MPI.
Generally OpenBLAS, MKL, BLIS and other threaded BLAS libraries will maximize the number of threads used.
So if you have a computer with 12 cores. Then the BLAS library will typically use 12 threads.
These threads are per MPI core.
So if you do:
mpirun -np 12 siesta ...

you'll typically run 12 MPI processes, each running 12 threads, resulting in 144 processes running on your computer. This causes sever load imbalance.
So, all BLAS libraries (at least that I know of) will use the environment variable OMP_NUM_THREADS to specify the actual used number of threads.
I.e.
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
mpirun -np 12 siesta ...

will cause each MPI process to only use 1 thread.
This will not result in an oversubscription, and should provide the best performance.
Generally one can minimize the RAM usage by decreasing MPI processes, and increasing OpenMP threads. However, you should always ensure that MPI * OpenMP <= CORES where CORES in the above case is 12.
Hence you could do:
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
mpirun -np 6 siesta ...

resulting in 12 cores being used.
For HPC environments you'll typically also deal with compute nodes which has 2 sockets.
In such nodes you don't want the threads to live on two different sockets. The solution (for OpenMPI) is to specify how the MPI processes should be distributed. In the following example, each CPU has 12 cores, and there are 2 sockets (total 12 * 2 = 24 cores), lets do an example with 4 threads per MPI-process, hence 6 MPI processes, this can be done via:
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
export OMP_PROC_BIND=true
mpirun -np 6 --map-by ppr:3:socket:pe=4 -x OMP_NUM_THREADS -x OMP_PROC_BIND siesta ...

this will correctly bind 3 MPI processes per socket, each MPI process will occupy 4 cores, which will then be used by OpenMP.
Two final notes:

Some processors are built with threading technologies that for some low compute loads may allow two threads to run per physical core in a reasonable efficient manner.  In this case, assuming there are N physical cores, the operating system will report 2N logical cores.  For applications with intensive compute loads, as is the case of siesta, one generally has to completely forget about logical cores, since that kind of double subscription per physical core won't work well.  In other words, in the discussion above about processes, threads and cores, the condition should be number(MPI ranks) * number(OpenMP threads) <= number(physical cores).
In OpenBLAS, as documented here, one can also adjust at runtime the number of OpenBLAS threads while not affecting the number of threads used by other parts of the application.  This is done by defining the OpenBLAS-specific environment variable OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS.  In order to prevent OpenBLAS from threading, one would
$ export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1




well, it was not about compiling siesta with openmp, it was rather to limit the openblas auto threading to not use all threads.

@nickpapior feel free to edit my Community Wiki answer. My answer was based on the comment that contained "I recompiled siesta with openmp on, then, I use 24 cores and each cores with 8 threads to rerun the calculations, I found the speed is indeed faster than ever", but I understand that there was more to the discussion.

changed it, thanks!

@nickpapior well explanation,Sir!

@xinbiaowang you have ~10 questions, and you haven't marked any of them as answered (while many of them are actually answered). Please follow this guideline for all your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. If you don't do this, people will not be encouraged to answer your questions.

@nickpapior Thanks for reminding me. Sir. I am not familiar with the rules of this website. I will mark my questions as the guidelines requested immediately.

@nickpapior Could you help me promote my new questions? Few people have seen my questions.

@xinbiaowang please add a bounty on anything that you would like promoted. Click "start a bounty".

@NikeDattani-NoFreeTime Thank you for your advice! Sir. I will do it!

@nickpapior Sir, my question https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/13358/siesta-why-is-the-current-0-for-v-0-8 comes from your tutorials. Could you give me some suggestions?
